# JHipster Entity sub generator - updating - master.xml duplicate entries

Tags: jhipster

I am having issues using the "entity" sub generator when attempting update an existing entity.

After running:

```
jhipster entity <existingEntity>
```

..and answering the subsequent questions e.g. *"Yes, add more fields and relationships"*, I am asked if I want to overwrite files (which I do), however one of those is `master.xml`. It adds 2 new entries:

> include
>   file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20170604231923_added_entity_Car.xml"
>   relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>

**And**

> include
>   file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20170604231923_added_entity_constraints_Car.xml"
>   relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>

This is in **addition** to:

> include
>   file="config/liquibase/changelog/20170604231923_added_entity_Car.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>

**And**

> include
>   file="config/liquibase/changelog/20170604231923_added_entity_constraints_Car.xml"
>   relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>

... which already existed (from JDL import).

They both refer to the same files. Except the new entries include **classpath**. Anyway, the end result when selecting overwrite and doing a mvn clean install are errors about the entity and constraints already existing (as you would expect). Am I missing a trick here? Should I be not allowing the overwrite in this case? (I had assumed this would just work).

JHipster version is 4.6.2 (I recently updated it) and I've not used the sub generator before as originally did an import from JDL studio.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Hi, I would like to mention, these are two different issues, if you could create two different questions.

#1 Probably is a bug in Jhipster, should try to reproduce in a new project again. If you face the same issue, then report it to Bug tracker.

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues?q=is%3Aopen

#2 May be fix for #1 could solve it, but I have not yet started working on Angular2 so I am not aware of it.

Comment: also can you share your entity.json file. It would be under the folder ".jhipster"

Comment: Yes #1 is very likely a bug related to this change https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6121 in 4.6.2. Incremental migrations is being improved https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/5954

Comment: @SumitVairagar Thanks ~ I have created [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45290211/2440661) question for the second issue.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thank you ~ Do you want me to create a separate github issue as Sumit has suggested? I see you linked this question to the potentially breaking change so might not be necessary?

Comment: Please comment the existing issue as I don't really understand how you reached this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved now.

I had a mismatch between the version the project was upgraded to (v4.6.2) and the global JHipster Generator (v4.6.1).

Updating the JHipster Generator version to v4.6.2 resolved the issues.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. If this question is the same as your other one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290211/jhipster-entity-sub-generator-no-properties-in-common-with-type-component - please flag it as such.

Comment: @ChrisF Thanks ~ they are distinct issues which happen to be caused by the same problem. I originally created one question but decided to split it out into two as per suggestion from commenter. How would you like it flagging?

Comment: if they're not the same problem then there's no flagging to do. It's just that duplicate answers are automatically flagged by the system as they usually indicate issues that require moderator attention. This is one of the rare cases where the same answer is an, albeit slightly unsatisfactory, answer to multiple questions.